ArrayList or HashSet, which collection class provides the fastest access to the elements, In Java?
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
         OR
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();

ArrayList implements RandomAccess Interface and the Set uses a hashing mechanism to store or fetch the value of the collection object. So Which collection will provide the fastest access elements from the object?

ArrayList uses an array behind the scenes. So it provides O(1) access to an element by their index. A Set<E> doesn't provide a E get(int index) method

You cannot access a Set by index, so your question is moot.

You need a huge list or set before access time matters. Don’t let access time determine your choice until you have determined that you have a bottleneck that affects response times negatively (and if you ever come to that point, you should probably consider more options than the two you mention).

Set has no index
Your question makes no sense.

A List has a sequence, so you can access by index.
A Set has no sequence, no predictable iteration order, by definition. So you cannot access by index.

Furthermore, note that in the latest versions of Java, List extends the interface SequencedCollection. Set & HashSet do not.
If you want a Set with a predictable iteration order, use an implementation of the sub-interface SequencedSet. But that does not give  you access by index.
Premature optimization
Do not fall into the trap of premature optimization. See the Comment above. See Is premature optimization really the root of all evil?.
Generally best to choose the Collection class that makes sense for your data and your logic. If you suspect a performance bottleneck, test to prove that alleged bottleneck. Only then should you think about optimizing.

Well, you could "convert" a Set to an array with the toArray() method that has to maintain the order of the provided iterator under a certain condition. So you could access elements by an index. HashSet is not meeting that condition so the index is not stable as I would call it.

@cyberbrain A Set has no predictable iteration order. Calling toArray does not bestow a predictable iteration order.

@KonstantinMakarov That fact is not relevant to the Question here. Having duplicates has nothing to do with access by index.
